# Hide version history in Word

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning, word

I would like to hide the previous versions of a document when it is opened in Word etc.  We do not want read only users to be able to see previous major versions.  Can this done?

Answer (score 1):

a. Create a new Permission Level copied from "Read" permission

b. Remove "View Versions" option from the new permission level

c. Set that new permission level to the users or groups

Following are the steps...

1. Go to the Site Collection > Top level Site > Site Settings > Site Permissions
2. Click on "Permission Levels" from Ribbon > Permission Tools > Manage
3. You will see list of permission levels available for the site collection. Now click on "Read".
4. You will see list of permissions for Read...scroll down the page and click on "Copy Permission Level".
5. Put a Name & Description and uncheck "View Versions"...then scroll down and click "Create".
6. Now your new permission level is ready...apply this to respective users or groups in the site.

For more details on permission levels [click here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-create-and-edit-Permission-Levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).